# Hibernate - TableView bindings

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

I am trying to use Hibernate in my project. I have Class that is binded to DB Table. Few of columns from that Table have relations to other table (because of big amount of data in main class). Everything works fine. But I dont know how to bind that properly to TableView.

```
@FXML TableView<ClassExample> ExampleTableView;
@FXML TableColumn<ClassExample, Integer> tableViewColumnID;
@FXML TableColumn<ClassExample2, String> tableViewColumnString;

tableViewColumnID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClassExample,Integer>("idZap"));
tableViewColumnString.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ClassExample2, String>("INFO"));
```

For first column everything is ok. But how to bind ClassExample2.getINFO (Column "INFO"), which is a part of ClassExample?

I have tried this and it works - but can I do it wthout lambda?:

```
tableViewColumnString.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getClassExample2().getINFO()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `PropertyValueFactory` to access a "property of a property", so you have to provide your own implementation of a `Callback<CellDataFeatures<ClassExample>, ObservableValue<String>>` somehow. There's no requirement to use a lambda expression, but it is far less verbose than the equivalent anonymous inner class:

```
tableViewColumnString.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ClassExample>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ClassExample> cellData) {
       return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getClassExample2().getINFO());
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. That is what I was looking for :)